# Is there a way to insert multiple rows into a table with default values for all columns?

Tags: postgresql, default-value, postgresql-9.4

I can insert multiple rows into a table with default values for all columns the [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) way:

```
create table course(course_id serial primary key);

do $$
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    insert into course default values;
  end loop;
end;$$;
```

Is there a way of doing the same with a single SQL statement?

Comment: Extensive answer to a closely related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `generate_series()` and ctes. Tested in [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/OSXKIT61579):

```
create table t
( tid serial primary key,
  i int default 0,
  name text default 'Jack'
) ;


with ins as
  (insert into t (i, name)               -- all the columns except any serial
   values (default, default)
   returning i, name
  )
insert into t 
  (i, name)
select 
  ins.i, ins.name
from 
  ins cross join generate_series(1, 9);  -- one less than you need
```

---

For the case when there is only one column and it's a `serial`, I see no way to use the `default`. Using the generate_series is straight-forward:

```
insert into course
  (course_id)
select
  nextval('course_course_id_seq')
from
  generate_series(1, 10);
```

---

- If there are other, more "peculiar" default values, like a UUID function or the non-standard `clock_timestamp()`, the statement will have to be adjusted accordingly, like the serial case.

---

An idea to improve came from the similar question: [Inserting dummy data into an empty table having a primary key integer field GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317108/), using the **`OVERRIDING USER VALUE`** option in the `INSERT` statement. This is available only in versions 10+, not in 9.6 and previous.
Note: it does NOT work if the table has a single column which is `serial`.

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/8qgfwMPm):

```
create table t
( tid serial primary key,
  i int default 0,
  name text default 'Jack'
) ;

insert into t (i)
  OVERRIDING USER VALUE
select null
from generate_series(1, 10) as gs(i) ;
```

Answer (score 11):

There's no rule that select statements must return one or more columns.

If the select returns zero columns in several rows you will get rows inserted with all default values.

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
  SELECT FROM generate_series(1,10);
```