# PostgreSQL 10 Identity Column gets "null value" when inserting multiple rows with default keyword

Tags: postgresql, identity, postgresql-10

I recently upgraded from PostgreSQL 9.5 to PostgreSQL 10. One of the nifty features in PostgreSQL 10 is the new [*identity column*](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) type, an alternative to PostgreSQL' [*serial*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) pseudo-type. Official documentation for identity column can be found one the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html) page.

However, when inserting multiple rows into a table with a `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` column *and* using the keyword `DEFAULT` to get the next ID value, the default value is coming back as `null`.

For example, let's say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  t text
);
CREATE TABLE
```

Inserting a single row with the `DEFAULT` keyword seems to work fine.

```
INSERT INTO test (id, t) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'a');
INSERT 0 1
```

Inserting multiple rows does not.

```
INSERT INTO test (id, t) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'b'), (DEFAULT, 'c');
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, b).
```

Inserting multiple rows using an implicit default also works.

```
INSERT INTO test (t) VALUES ('d'), ('e');
INSERT 0 2
```

The problem specified above does not appear to be present when using the `SERIAL` column pseudo-type.

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id SERIAL,
  t text
);
CREATE TABLE

INSERT INTO test2 (id, t) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'a'), (DEFAULT, 'b');
INSERT 0 2
```

So my question is: am I missing something? Is the `DEFAULT` keyword just not expected to work with the new *identity column*? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in fact a bug. I verified it. I went to go see if it was filed and it seems it already is. It's not just filed, [the commit is there.](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/16/1405/)

You can see their test, exactly like yours

```
+-- VALUES RTEs
+INSERT INTO itest3 VALUES (DEFAULT, 'a');
+INSERT INTO itest3 VALUES (DEFAULT, 'b'), (DEFAULT, 'c');
+SELECT * FROM itest3;
```

So just wait, it's there for PostgreSQL 10.2.

## Possible work around for PostgreSQL < 10.2

If you absolutely must have this, and using the implicit column isn't acceptable. One easy solution would be to retrieve the sequence with the [catalog info function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-info.html)

```
pg_get_serial_sequence(table_name, column_name)
```

Which I believe *should work*, and to set that as a default.

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY test
  ALTER COLUMN id
  DEFAULT nextval('seqname');
```

Comment: Thanks for checking that it's already been filed (and committed). My plan is to continue using sequences where necessary until 10.2

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug as @Evan discovered, so until it is fixed we have to work around it.

As you probably know, it's easy to work around the case for multiple column inserts where not all values are `default` — just omit the column(s) where you want the `default` value inserted entirely, *`default` is the default*:

> ```
> INSERT INTO test (t) VALUES ('b'), ('c');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | t 
> -: | :-
>  1 | b 
>  2 | c
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b08f01fa0a9e8a596980729312eb2741)*

If there are *multiple columns* and you want them *all* to be default, [you can still use a CTE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89544/1396):

> ```
> WITH w AS (INSERT INTO test (t) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING t )
> INSERT INTO test (t) SELECT w.t FROM w CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | t  
> -: | :--
>  1 | foo
>  2 | foo
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=799dfbe823c885f932472996183a4690)*

Unfortunately, there is no easy workaround if you need all columns to be populated with `default`:

> [For the case when there is only one column and it's a serial, I see no way to use the default.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89544/1396)